# Bootstrap calendar control to show upto current week in active?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, fullcalendar

Bootstrap calendar control to show up to current week in active. Any solution would be grateful received.

For exampe: consider today is Tuesday, but calendar should up to  Sunday in active. i.e last all days & the current week in active?

I'm using php, javascript, jquery and bootstrap. I used this function called available:

```
$('#fromdate').datepicker({beforeShowDay: available, dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
```

If I get current week and last two week dates. I will store in to any array and call the function. So the dates which are in array will be enabled, and the dates which are not in array are disabled.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Actually i'm using php,java script,jquery,bootstrap.  i used  this function called available     $('#fromdate').datepicker({beforeShowDay: available, dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});

Comment: if i get current week &  last two week dates. I will store in to any array & call the function.So the dates which are in array will be enabled, and the dates which are not in array are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `minDate` option

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max